# facing error 443 while performing android app load testing in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, manual-testing

I am a complete beginner in Jmeter and facing error 443 while performing android app Load testing in Jmeter(5.4.1). I have followed all required steps to connect jmeter to mobile apk.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what "all required steps" you "have followed" we cannot provide any comprehensive input.

"All required steps" are:

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and [install it onto Android device](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/2844832?hl=en)
3. If you're running [Android 7.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Nougat) or higher:

   - In the [application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) section of your application manifest add the following attribute

     android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config
   - Add the following file to your application [resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) folder

     ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <network-security-config>
        <debug-overrides>
          <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
            <certificates src="user" />
          </trust-anchors>
        </debug-overrides>
      </network-security-config>
     ```
   - [Re-build your application in debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode) by invoking `gradlew assembleDebug` command
   - Install the debug version of the .apk onto your Android device
4. You should be able to record now, if still not - check out [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file and [Android device log](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat)

More information: [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices)